# Linked-list addition yielding incorrect result

Tags: python, linked-list

Here is some python code for a simple problem that I'm trying to solve from this leetcode [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/).

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>   Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
>   Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
>   Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
> ```

I can't figure out where the bug is in my code. The output of what the code does when ran is at the bottom.

```
import unittest

def addTwoNumbers(l1, l2):
    Rhead1 = reverseLL(l1) # 3 -> 4 -> 2
    Rhead2 = reverseLL(l2) # 4 -> 6 -> 5

    node1 = Rhead1
    node2 = Rhead2
    carry = 0
    newLL = None

    while node1 and node2:
        arith = node1.data + node2.data + carry
        # print('node1: {0} + node2: {1} + carry: {2} = arith: {3}'.format(node1.data, node2.data, carry, arith))
        carry = 0
        if arith >= 10: carry, arith = divmod(arith, 10)
        
        if newLL: newLL.next = Node(arith)
        else: newLL = Node(arith)

        node1, node2 = node1.next, node2.next
    
    return newLL

def reverseLL(head):
    prev = None
    node = head

    while node:
        next = node.next
        node.next = prev
        prev = node
        node = next
    
    return prev

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data, self.next = data, next
    
    def __str__(self):
        string = str(self.data)
        if self.next:
            string += ' -> ' + str(self.next)
        return string

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_addTwoNumbers(self):
        head1 = Node(2, Node(4, Node(3, None)))    # (2 -> 4 -> 3)
        head2 = Node(5, Node(6, Node(4, None)))    # (5 -> 6 -> 4)
        expected = Node(7, Node(0, Node(8, None))) # (7 -> 0 -> 8)
        print('actual:',str(addTwoNumbers(head1, head2)))
        print('expected:',str(expected))
        # self.assertAlmostEqual(str(addTwoNumbers(head1, head2)), str(expected))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
actual: 7 -> 8
expected: 7 -> 0 -> 8
```

Where am I not getting what is expected? I'm dumbfounded and I don't know why my code isn't working. Please help

Comment: Note that a good Stack Overflow question focuses on a specific, isolated problem, with only the shortest [mre] that lets others test the issue and determine whether it's resolved; if you haven't yet _found_ your problem, it's potentially too early to be asking here. (A good guideline is to try to make sure you're asking about why a specific language facility or library call isn't doing what you expect, as opposed to asking about *your code*; if you haven't determined which call it is that is doing something other than what you expect, the question is likely premature).

Comment: First off all, take a break. Take your mind off this for a while. Once back use a debugger or just add print statements in your methods to check and see if the logic you've written is valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with your newLL variable and how you're appending numbers to your linked list. You've created the head of that list and at most go upto the 2nd value with newLL.next, but you don't traverse through the list to add more. Here's a possible solution:

```
def addTwoNumbers(l1, l2):
    Rhead1 = reverseLL(l1) # 3 -> 4 -> 2
    Rhead2 = reverseLL(l2) # 4 -> 6 -> 5

    node1 = Rhead1
    node2 = Rhead2
    carry = 0
    newLL = None
    temp = None

    while node1 and node2:
        arith = node1.data + node2.data + carry
        # print('node1: {0} + node2: {1} + carry: {2} = arith: {3}'.format(node1.data, 
        #node2.data, carry, arith))
        carry = 0
        if arith >= 10: carry, arith = divmod(arith, 10)
    
        if newLL: 
            temp.next = Node(arith)
            temp = temp.next
        else: 
            newLL = Node(arith)
            temp = newLL

        node1, node2 = node1.next, node2.next

    return newLL
```

Answer (score 0):

Good job using `unittest` and `carry, arith = divmod(arith, 10)`!

---

Not sure about your bug, but we can use a sentinel node and solve the problem a bit easier.

This'll pass:

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, a, b):
        carry = 0
        sentinel = p = ListNode(0)
        while a or b or carry:
            if a:
                carry, a = carry + a.val, a.next
            if b:
                carry, b = carry + b.val, b.next
            carry, val = carry // 10, carry % 10
            p.next = p = ListNode(val)
        return sentinel.next
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.